# Javascript form validation not working

Tags: validation, forms

I have a simple form validation script:

```
function validate() {
    if(document.register.field.value == "") {
        alert("Please fill in all fields");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

the function is called using the onSubmit handler, but nothing happens when submit is clicked. It goes directly to the PHP script instead of javascript 'intercepting' it. Any thoughts?

Form HTML:

```
<form action='register.php' name='register' method='POST' onSubmit='return validate();'>
  <table>
         <tr>
             <td>
             Your Full Name:
             </td>
             <td>
             *<input class='req' type='text' name='fullname'>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
             Email Address:
             </td>
             <td>
             *<input class='req' type='text' name='email'>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
             Home Phone Number:
             </td>
             <td>
             *<input class='req' type='text' name='homephone'>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
             Cell Phone Number:
             </td>
             <td>
             *<input class='req' type='text' name='cellphone'>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
             Address:
             </td>
             <td>
             *<input class='req' type='text' name='address'>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            * indicates a required field
            </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Here's a minimal jsfiddle that might help: http://jsfiddle.net/WqFzL/ I like getting form elements by ID as shown, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your validate function has a syntax error. Replace the square bracket ] with a right brace }:

```
function validate() {
    if(document.register.field.value == "") {
        alert("Please fill in all fields");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```